# Generating hydrogen from moving water

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electricity, water, hydrogen

I am a high school student and I have planned to participate in national innovation award of my country. In this competition, prototype of innovation is needed. I have created a design but I lack guidance and my teacher refused to help me. The design is:

"Imagine water flowing through high magnetic field.
Taking simple case(uniform magnetic field), we get[image]Using the induced current, electrolysis of water could be conducted and hydrogen could be separated.[image]Taking achievable value for various parameters(searched on internet for some values) , I got the following answer.
[image]Accordingly approx 1kg of hydrogen in a day can be generated.

Overall it will look like :[image]

So, please tell me if this design will work or not? Also please tell the area where I am wrong.
This is basic and simple model and could be made more efficient.

Please guide me.

Comment: Please add a reference to your previous question to this question, as they are related.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't follow the details of your calculation fully, but it seems like you are confusing the speed of the water through a magnet and speed of free electrons that would produce a current.

I could be wrong, but as far I can tell, moving water through a magnet would not cause electrolysis. For example, there is a technique in chemistry called NMR spectroscopy that involves spinning tubes of water in very high magnetic fields. From experience, these tubes are stable and do not undergo water splitting.

Now, even if you could induce a current, you'd need to consider what's called the "Faradaic efficiency." It corresponds to the percentage of electrons (in Faraday's law) that go into the desired chemical reaction. Generally, in the absence of a platinum catalyst, it is difficult to channel those electrons into water splitting.

There's a lot of literature out there on the use of electricity to split water. Look up "electrolytic water splitting" to learn more. e